# how to Call web service using stored procedure which returns json and store data in table using sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how to Call web service using stored procedure which returns json and store data in table using sql server?

```
  ==============
  Declare @Object as Int;
  Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

--Code Snippet
 Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
 Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
             'WEB SERVICE LINK', --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
             'false'
 Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
 Exec sp_OAGetProperty@Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

 Select @ResponseText

 Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: Use SSIS, don't call from SQL

Comment: Use some other language/framework - C# app, SSIS, or anything really, but not SQL. It's not really designed for that sort of thing. C# has tools built in to call webservices and parse JSON etc, then it's easy to save to the DB.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions... #gbn and #ADyson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Object AS INT ;
            DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000) ;
            DECLARE @Url AS VARCHAR(1000) ;
            SET @Url = 'Web service'

            EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT ; --
            EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @Url,'false'           
            EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
            EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

            SELECT  @ResponseText

            EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object

            DECLARE @handle INT 
            DECLARE @PrepareXmlStatus INT  


            EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT,
                @ResponseText
```